# ClassCastException with Java's TreeMap when using custom classes as the key

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception, treemap

The following code throws a `ClassCastException` when I try to get a mapping with my custom `Dog` class as the key:

```
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class testMain {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            TreeMap<Dog, String> m = new TreeMap<Dog, String>();
            m.put(new Dog("Fido"), "woof");

            // this line produces a ClassCastException
            String sound = m.get(new Dog("Fido"));

            System.out.println(sound);
    }
}
```

The dog class is simply:

```
public class Dog {

    String name;

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I don't see why `TreeMap` would be casting the `Dog` class in the first place. *Why do I get a ClassCastException when using a custom made class as the key?* Any ideas on how to fix this code would be appreciated as well!

Comment: And implement `equals` and `hashCode()` because otherwise you will not be able to retrieve the entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TreeMap sorts elements in insertion time according to ordering of their keys. Hence the objects that are used as keys must implement `Comparable` interface.

Please refer to an edit I have made to your `Dog` class. It works now:

```
public static class Dog implements Comparable<Dog> {

    String name;

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Dog obj) {
        return name.compareTo(obj.name);
    }
}
```

**EDIT: The reason for ClassCastException exception:**

If you see the line `Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;` in the code of the `get` method of the `TreeMap` you will see that it's trying to cast your key to `Comparable` object. Your object was not an instanceof `Comparable`.

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
     // Offload comparator-based version for sake of performance
     if (comparator != null)
         return getEntryUsingComparator(key);
     if (key == null)
         throw new NullPointerException();
     Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
     Entry<K,V> p = root;
     while (p != null) {
         int cmp = k.compareTo(p.key);
         if (cmp < 0)
             p = p.left;
         else if (cmp > 0)
             p = p.right;
         else
             return p;
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still confused why the `ClassCastException` would arise in the first place though. Why not something like a `YouGotToImplementComparable` exception? How does this error have anything to do with casting?

Comment: You get a `ClassCastException` because the `TreeMap` tries to cast your custom class to `comparable` interface so that it can call `compareTo` method on it. Since you didn't implement the `Comparable` interface the casting gives error.

Answer (score 1):

Dog must implement Comparable if you want to use it as key in a TreeMap without a Comparator

Answer (score 0):

You have to let your Dog classes implements the `Comparable` interface.

```
class Dog implements Comparable<Dog>
```

From the doc :

> The map is sorted according to the [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of its keys